# Use separate DB for delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have a situation where I need to have delayed_job use a custom backend on a separate DB/table.

So essentially force it to use a separate schema vs. the one my app primarily uses.

Any ideas on how to do this?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could make some of your models connect to a different database and use different tables.

Specify the configurations for your new db in the `database.yml`

```
delayed_jobs_db_connection:
  adapter: mysql # or any other adapter
  database: delayed_jobs_db
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
```

And in the model one would establish the connection to this database using [`establish_connection`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-establish_connection). You could also specify all the config directly in the model, keeping it in a config is just a better way. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi - I did do this - but delayed_job's backend still is searching for 'delayed_jobs' vs. my new table in the separate DB.  Seems DJ doesn't allow you to set the backend...

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been asked quite a bit time ago, but I faced the same challenge and this easy approach worked for me:

Just added in the top of the file:

```
require 'delayed_job'
require 'delayed_job_active_record'
class Delayed::Job
  establish_connection {"adapter"=>"mysql2",
   "host"=>"127.0.0.1",
   "username"=>"root",
   "password"=>"aaaaa",
   "port"=>3306,
   "database"=>"users",
   "reconnect"=>true,
   "pool"=>10}
end
```

Comment: when you say "added in the top of the file" which file do you mean?